# How to kill specific Jupyter server from terminal?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

How can I kill a running Jupyter server by port number from the terminal? I can find the localhost ports with `jupyter notebook list` but I can't find a jupyter command to terminate.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose you have obtained the port number using `jupyter notebook list`, say it is `8888`. You can then use

```
fuser 8888/tcp
```

to see the `PID` of the process using this port. Then use `kill -9 PID` to kill it.